# Is there a way to pipe all Serial output into a Software Serial?

Tags: arduino, pipeline, uart, atmega, software-serial

I've build a micro controller based on the ATmega644 and I'm running an arduino core on it.

Some libs I use have debug output via Serial.
Thing is, I'm using UART for RS485.

Debug output of my code goes out via Software Serial.

Is there a way to pipe all Serial output of the libs to a Software Serial without changing the libs?